# C# Windows Mobile MC67 Mobile Computer , how to print using Zebra RW420 via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, printing, bluetooth, windows-mobile-6.5, zebra-printers

I am developing a project for Windows Mobile 6.5 MC67 Mobile computer.
I have to connect my MC67 Mobile computer to the Zebra printer via Bluetooth.

I am developing in C# with Visual Studio 2005 Standard Edition.

How to do this module.I donot know where to start working on it

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may start with http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-windows-mobile.html. It should run with VS2005 too.

You may also simple start with a manual BT discovery and Serial Port assignment to the found BT printer.

The next is to use a SerialPort in your app to send the print commands to the printer. It is just a serial communication.

Then you have to learn the Zebra printer's printing command language to get some printout on the printer. Be aware that Zebra printers may come with different print command interpreter, for example ZPL or ZSimm or ESC/P. Look at the printer programmers guide starting at the printers support site. For example the Zebra QL-220: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile/ql-220-plus.html

There is also a generic printing SDK called PrinterCE: http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF.htm. It supports various printers like the Zebra MZ,RW,QL,Cameo series ( http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrintersSupported.htm). PrinterCE enables easy changing the printer model without much change to your code. It works similar to a desktop PC printer driver and renders pages as graphics internally.

I assume there are already a lot of answers here about Zebra mobile printing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply josef. I found the code to send the print job to the printer.But I could not find the code for connecting the Bluetooth printer to the Windows mobile.Please help me as I am new to C# coding.

Comment: See 32feet.net or search for "compact+framework+bluetooth+RegisterDevice". I have some code using 32feet at http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCommAppCFbtSearch

Comment: Here is an example of how to connect to a Zebra printer using Bluetooth in C#: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1378297725718&answerid=16777216&iqaction=5&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fkb%2Findex%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DSA282%26actp%3Dsearch%26viewlocale%3Den_US&highlightinfo=4194569,170,186#.

Comment: I forgot to mention a sample using 32feet to discover and connect BT printer: http://code.google.com/p/win-mobile-code/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCommAppCFbtSearch